# Extend Laravel class used by vendor

Tags: php, laravel, class, laravel-5

### What I want

Extend Laravel class used by vendor, specifically this one: https://github.com/laracasts/flash and the `Flash/Message.php` class.

### Why I want

In order to add some class parameters for customization purposes.

### What have I tried

Everything I found googling and browsing other questions.

I have created my own service provider:

```
use Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider as BaseServiceProvider;

class FlashServiceProvider extends BaseServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton( 'flash', function() {
            return $this->app->make( 'App\Extensions\Laracasts\Flash\FlashNotifier' );
        } );
    }
}
```

And even succedeed adding custom function to the `App\Extensions\Laracasts\Flash\FlashNotifier` class.

### Still wont work

Even though I have extended the `FlashNotifier` class successfully. I'm still having issues with it, because it keeps using the original `Messages` class, instead of mine.

### Question

How can I force my extended `FlashNotifier` class to use my version of `Messages` class and not the original one?

Comment: Did you register your custom service provider?

Comment: Yes I did. `App\Providers\FlashServiceProvider::class` (even tried to remove original provider line `Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class`).

Comment: can you post the git repository url?

Comment: @JeffPuckett It's in the question.

Comment: yeah I'm a contributor to the original package, I was asking about your app repo.

Comment: overriding it is not a problem, so I'm curious to see where you've got the wires crossed.

Comment: @JeffPuckett My app is in a private repo. However, I think there is not much to see, I will try to provide everything in order: working extension of FlashNotice class: https://pastebin.com/phrgRVNW. Message class: https://pastebin.com/qbdvA1U7 + the provider line in previous comment + service provider class from the question. Tree: https://i.imgur.com/Bw1yLG5.png

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the classes, you could take a different approach.

Create a fork of [laracasts/flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash), and then you can load that into your project

Composer documentation for [loading a package from a VCS repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

From the docs

> There are a few use cases for this. The most common one is maintaining your own fork of a third party library. If you are using a certain library for your project and you decide to change something in the library, you will want your project to use the patched version...